# Difference between shuffle_batch() and batch() in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, records

I'm using `tf.train.shuffle_batch()` and `tf.train.batch()` to read a .record file with two classes and three examples per class. If I want two batches of three examples, I put `num_epochs = 1` in `string_input_producer` so I'll get two batches of three examples of each but both functions return two shuffled batches every time I call them.

What is the difference between this two functions?

Thanks!

Comment: The docs are super clear about it. Even the names are super clear. What other explanation do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf._train.shuffle_batch()` will return records in random order, while `tf.train.batch()` will return them in sequential order from your source. One or the other may be more helpful depending on what you are trying to accomplish. I'd say go with `shuffle_batch` because it adds extra randomization to the learning process, but think first of what makes sense given your task.

Comment: It's true. But if you set `dynamic_pad = True` or\and `allow_smaller_final_batch = True` it produces shuffled batches using `tf.train.batch`